# How do i add dependencies to component in dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I want to add a component to root component using new dagger2 approach.

It's working fine with old approach where we create component and provide manually all other component and module.

But i haven't any idea how to do it with new dagger2 approach.

```
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class},dependencies = CoreComponent.class)

public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication>

 {

  @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApplication> {}

}
```

any one have any idea how to add the  Core Component.class to App Component .

Answer (score 0):

`AndroidInjector` has a predefined `inject` method, but is otherwise treated just like any `@Component`. So I suppose you can write your own `AppComponent.Builder` from scratch:

```java
// In AppComponent, which extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication>
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    Builder coreComponent(CoreComponent coreComponent);

    // You may need this for installed @Modules too:
    // public abstract Builder appModule(AppModule appModule);

    // The following setter and build are from AndroidInjector.Builder
    @BindsInstance
    Builder myApplication(MyApplication myApplication);

    AppComponent build();
}
```

Then to build an `AppComponent`:

```java
CoreComponent coreComponent = /* ... */;
AppComponent appComponent =
    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .coreComponent(coreComponent)
        .myApplication(myApplication)
        .build();
```

I cannot comment on whether this is recommended though, because the `dagger.android` examples seem to prefer subcomponents over component dependencies.